# How do you detect a string within a file name in batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to sort a series of folders containing thousands of company documents into an alphabetically sorted list of individual folders with the naming scheme "last name, first name".

The documents I am trying to sort have the name of their subject in the file's name. For example, one file could be called "`Baggins_Frodo_Resume`" or "`Snow, Jon - Resume`". I need to sort those files into folders called "`Snow, John`" and "`Baggins, Frodo`" respectively.

I have the name of each folder on a text file called "list of names.txt" in the format:

```
Last First
Baggins Frodo
Snow Jon
```

---

Written out in plain English, I would like to have the batch file follow the steps outlined below. I used brackets around terms that should be variables.

1. Read the first line in the file "`list of names.txt`"
2. Assign the last name from the list to the variable [last name] and the first name to the variable [first name]
3. Within directory [C:\folder that needs sorting]...
4. if [file name] contains the text [last name] AND [first name] then...
5. Copy [file] to a folder called [last name, first name]
6. Repeat until no more files containing the name exist
7. Move on to the next line on "list of names.txt" and repeat.

I apologize in advance for my erroneous code, I am usually just barely able to figure out the basics of batch when I need it but this time I'm really struggling.

[I had some trouble formatting the code below so here is a link to what I have with adjusted spacing and highlights.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTN_4BvdhbZYGwQAYcCteYFXeHBlpmq6_F7QfMsYx-6H5xzd4t5OCWl5cBS_pU5kWNA92U4oi6JZiDh/pub)

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem Read the first name on the list and assign it to a variable
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ("list of names.txt") do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "%%f"') do (
        for %%N in ("%%F") do (
            set name=%%~NN
            set dest="%%~NN"
            set the directory
            cd /d %userprofile%\desktop\"folder to sort"
            rem find each file within the directory that contains the current name from the list
            find /I . -name "*%%~NN*" ! -name "*:*" -print if errorlevel 0 then(
                rem copy matching files to their respective folder
                copy "%%F" "%%~NN"\!name!!ext!"
            ) else (
echo No additional matches found
pause
end
            )
        )
    )
)
```

There are a couple of issues here that I would really appreciate help fixing.

1. As my question suggests I'm not sure how to search just the name of each file for matches and not the entire contents of the file.
2. Additionally, I'm not sure how to separate the first/last names from "list of names.txt" to assign them to separate variables.
3. This is my first post on stackoverflow and in the future, I would like to be able to adjust the color of my code properly. I see in the help section that " In many cases, the syntax highlighting language will be inferred from the question's tags," but that didn't occur in my case. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you all so much for the detailed suggestions! I had not expected so many fantastic replies this quickly. I will go through all of these today to see how they work and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I offer you a different approach?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Within directory [C:\folder that needs sorting]...
cd "C:\folder that needs sorting"

rem Process the list of folder names. Note that %%a=Last and %%b=First
rem Note that "usebackq" option is needed because the file name is enclosed in quotes
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%a in ("C:\folder\of\list of names.txt") do (

   rem Move all file names with the name scheme "Last*First*.*" into "Last, First" folder
   move "%%a*%%b*.*" "C:\base\folder\of\%%a, %%b"

)
```

Comment: Ooh - Danger, Will Robinson! Consider `Snowden, Jonathon - something` which will match `snow jon`.

Comment: Aacini, thank you so much for responding. Out of the three great replies I had to work with I choose yours simply because I could figure out how to get it to work - thanks for making this easy to understand. Magoo brings up a valid point in saying that theoretically names contained within other names could lead to improper sorting but, luckily, I did not have that problem in this case.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TX0PUQvqGLLlCL3tMWJjA9xSa5isZRmKIQpnx1lWIOM/edit?usp=sharing) to the code with the revisions detailed below. I added three commands to 1. allow the file to search subfolders, 2. make named folders that do not exist and, 3. move files named first/last in addition to last/first.
ADDITION 1: for /r "%userprofile%\desktop\records" %%g in (.) do (
cd %%g
ADDITION 2: if not exist "%userprofile%\desktop\people\%%a, %%b" mkdir "%userprofile%\desktop\people\%%a, %%b"
ADDITION 3: move "%%b*%%a*.*" "%userprofile%\desktop\people\%%a, %%b"

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with `powershell`, I assume you are open to a solution using it. This code reads in the `list of names.txt` file as a CSV file, then iterates of the the files in the directory to see if there are matches. If there is, it moves the file to the new directory. When you are confident that the correct directories will be created and files moved appropriately, **remove the `-WhatIf` from both the `mkdir` and `Move-Item` commands**.

```
$thedir = 'C:\src\t\nc\files'
$newdir = 'C:\src\t\nc\new'
$listfile = 'list of names.txt'
$thefiles = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $thedir

Import-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path $thedir -ChildPath $listfile) -Delimiter ' ' |
    ForEach-Object {
        foreach ($file in $thefiles) {
            if (($file.Name -match $_.Last) -and ($file.Name -match $_.First) -and ($file.Name -ne $listfile)) {
                $dirname = $_.Last + ', ' + $_.first
                $newpath = Join-Path -Path $newdir -ChildPath $dirname
                if (-not (Test-Path -Path $newpath)) { mkdir -Path $newpath -WhatIf }
                Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $newpath -WhatIf
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I tested this code out by attempting to move a few files like "Snow, Jon Resume.txt" and "Frodo Baggins the champ.txt" from the source folder Desktop\Records into the destination folder Desktop\People\"Last, First" but the program output an error. [Here is a screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/BvEvpobtb7x4RBoz7) of what I saw.

Comment: It looks like you removed the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet, but did not remove it from the `mkdir` command. If the directory is not created, the `Move-Item` will fail.

Comment: I have also revised the code to skip the `list of names.txt` file. It probably should not be in the same directory as the files to move.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56380365.txt"
SET /a maxwords=0
rem for each line in the names file...to %%a
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 rem analyse line
 CALL :words %%a
 IF !wordcount! lss 0 GOTO :EOF 
 IF !wordcount! gtr !maxwords! SET /a maxwords=!wordcount!
)

:: Now have max # words in maxwords


:scandir
rem for each line in the names file...to %%a
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM how many words IN this line?
 CALL :words %%a
 IF !wordcount! equ %maxwords% (
  rem read entire source directory using first word found as a filter
  FOR /f "delims=" %%h IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\!#1!*" 2^>nul') DO (
   CALL :matchname "%%h"
  )
 )
)
SET /a maxwords-=1
IF %maxwords% gtr 0 GOTO scandir

GOTO :EOF

:: Establish "Wordcount" and words as #*; subdir
:words
CALL :clear#
SET /a wordcount=0
SET "allwords=%~1 %~2"
SET "subdir=%~1"
SET "subdir2=%~2"
:: error if more than 2 "words" provided
IF "%~3" neq "" ECHO error IN line %*&SET /a wordcount=-1&GOTO :EOF 
:wordloop
SET /a wordcount+=1
CALL :atom %allwords%
SET "#%wordcount%=%car%"
IF DEFINED cdr SET "allwords=%cdr%"&GOTO wordloop
GOTO :EOF

:: First word to car, remainder to cdr
:atom
SET "car=%1"
SET "cdr="
:atomlp
SHIFT
IF "%1" neq "" SET "cdr=%cdr% %1"&GOTO atomlp
IF DEFINED cdr SET "cdr=%cdr:~1%"
GOTO :EOF 

:: remove variables starting #
:clear#
For %%b IN (#) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
GOTO :EOF

:: match filename in %1 to %maxwords% words in #* and move if matched
:matchname
SET "file=%~1"
SET /a match=1
:: replace commas, underscores [etc] with spaces
SET "file=%file:,= %"
SET "file=%file:_= %"

:matchloop
CALL :atom %file%
IF /i "%car%" neq "!#%match%!" GOTO :EOF
SET "file=%cdr%"
IF %match% neq %maxwords% SET /a match +=1&GOTO matchloop
:: all matched - move
MD "%destdir%\%subdir%, %subdir2%" 2>NUL >nul
ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%~1" "%destdir%\%subdir%, %subdir2%"
GOTO :eof
```

Landed up a little more complex than I'd anticipated. Since this used `delayedexpansion`, the usual warnings about special characters like `!` and `&` and other non-alphanumerics should be carefully processed. Normal alphanumerics and commas should be fine.

This approach first examines the names file - `q56380365.txt` on my system. Rather than simply two names, it allows a quoted string also, so a line like `"van der Waals" Johannes` can be used. Each line is passed to the `:words` routine which establishes `subdir` and `subdir2` for the subdirectory construction and also counts the individual words and places them in environment variables `#1`, `#2`..`#n`. If more than 2 strings are passed to `:words` then it returns `wordcount` as -1 to flag an error, having reported the line-contents. This ensures the two parts of the name are recognised correctly.

`:words` itself calls `:atom` which returns `car` as the first string in the list and `cdr` as the remaining strings. The reason for their being so named, I'll leave for someone else to ekthplain.

Having established the maximum number of words in the names file, we then scan the names file in reverse-order of the number of words - simply by reading the names file repeatedly, and matching against a reducing count. Where we have a match, we match the filenames using the first word as a filter. `:matchname` accepts the filename as `%1` and replaces any commas or underscores with spaces to the variable `file`. We then match the strings in turn against `#1...#n` until we reach the required number of matched words. If any words fail to match (I used `/i` to make the match case-insensitive) then the processing of this filename is abandoned. Having matched the required number of words, the required directory is created (2>nul suppresses the error message presuming the problem is "directory already exists") and the file is moved to the required subdirectory.

Note that the `md` is live, so the directories will be created, but the `move` command is simply `echo`ed for safety's sake. Remove the `echo` keyword here to actually move the file...

Note : fix - Comment 'how many words..' should be conventional `REM`, not `::` as labels are not allowed within a `for` loop (except in circumstances that have been published by others after commendable extensive research, but I have no intention of arranging since a blanket "always use `rem`" always works)

Comment: Magoo, thank you for this very thorough response. Coincidentally, I have benefitted from your high-quality answers to other posts before while working through different coding problems. I appreciate that this code attempts to account for uniquely challenging names and uncommon potential issues. I tested this out a few times since you posted it with fresh eyes each time but I have not been able to get it to move any files. The program consistently ends before getting to :matchloop.

Comment: Well - worked for me, but I didn't try the well-known troublemaker characters in a filename. I'd suggest that placing `echo matchname %*` after `:matchname` and `echo matchloop %* +++ %file%` after `:matchloop` may reveal the culprit. Batch isn't an ideal language for any variety of character-manipulation...